# Angular how to subscribe to interface changes?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to subscribe to my interface and watch for changes, but I have errors.

1. Getting data from api and asigning it to this.candidateProfile :

   ```
    export interface CandidateProfile {
    about: string,
    c_id: {},
    certificates_training: [],
    city: string,
    country: string,
    currency: string,
    email: string,
    expectedpayhourly: boolean,
    expectedpayhourlyend: number,
    expectedpayhourlystart: number,
    expectedpaymonthly: {},
    expectedpaymonthlyend: number,
    expectedpaymonthlystart: number,
    experience: [],
    firstname: string,
    hobbies: {},
    jobskills: [],
    langugaes: {},
    lastname: string,
    personalskills: [],
    photo: string,
    remotework: boolean,
    role: string,
    studies: {},
    willingtorelocate: {},
    willingtorelocatecity: {},
    worktype: string
     }
   ```

Auth.service.ts :

```
candidateProfile: Observable<CandidateProfile>;

getProfile(id, token) {
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
  })
};

this.http.get(`users/${id}`, httpOptions).subscribe(data => {
  this.candidateProfile = data;
},
  (error) => { console.log(error) },
  () => {
    console.log('got profile', this.candidateProfile);
  })

 }
```

Component.ts :

```
this.auth.candidateProfile.subscribe( data => {
console.log(data)
})
```

error :

### this.auth.candidateProfile.subscribe is not a function

Comment: `candidateProfile` in not an observable, it's just a `CandidateProfile`. You should subscribe to `getProfile` function instead. And add `RETURN this.http.get`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modify your auth service like following

```
export class AuthService {
    private _candidateProfile$: BehaviorSubject<CandidateProfile> = new BehaviorSubject(null);

    getProfile(id, token): void {
        const httpOptions = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
            })
        };

        this.http.get(`users/${id}`, httpOptions).subscribe(data => {
                this._candidateProfile$.next(data);
            },
            (error) => { console.log(error) },
            () => {
                console.log('got profile', data);
            })
    }

    get candidateProfile$(): Observable<CandidateProfile> {
      return this._candidateProfile$.asObservable();
    }
}
```

then you can use as following :

```
this.auth.candidateProfile$.subscribe( data => {
console.log(data)
})
```

**Explication**

Goal is to have internal observable on this service which will broadcast your current candidate profile.

Anywhere on your application you can subscribe to it and get latest fetched profil without trigger again the `getProfile` method (and ajax request under the hood).

to make it more easy to consume out of `AuthService` i have create magic getter to abstract it.

```
get candidateProfile$(): Observable<CandidateProfile> {
  return this._candidateProfile$.asObservable();
}
```

it take your `BehaviorSubject` and turn it to simple `Observable`. Otherwise you allow `AuthService` consumer to next on your `Observable`, and it not what is expected.

the only one way to broadcast new `CandidateProfile` should be here :

```
 this.http.get(`users/${id}`, httpOptions).subscribe(data => {
      this._candidateProfile$.next(data);
 });
```

---

I also recommand you to change your `getProfile` like following

```
getProfile(id, token): Observable<CandidateProfile> {
    // [...]
    this.http.get(`users/${id}`, httpOptions).subscribe(data => {
           this._candidateProfile$.next(data);
        },
        // [...]
    );

    return this.candidateProfile$;
}
```

Like this you can consume your class as following :

```
// Fetch new profile.
this.auth.getProfile(id, token).subscribe();
// Fetch last requested profile.
this.auth.candidateProfile$.subscribe();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you subscribe to an observable, you subscribe to its value, which is not an observable. When you are doing:

```
this.candidateProfile = data;
```

You are essentially storing in candidateProfile the value that you got from the observable. Of course this data does not have the function 'subscribe' anymore since it's not an observable.

You should store in 'this.candidateProfile' the observable itself, not the value that you get from it. Like so:

```
this.candidateProfile = this.http.get(`users/${id}`, httpOptions);
```

Hope that I helped you, have a nice day!

Comment: each time you subscribe to `candidateProfile` will perform new ajax request, is not what is expected i guess.

Comment: Why? You will subscribe just once to it, inside the component you are using it or if you are using a service, each time you subscribe to the observable returned by the service call. 

You could also use the toPromise() function to convert the observable to a promise if you feel more comfortable with it. Notice that you will lose all the advantages of rxjs Observables by doing it this way.

Comment: goal is to retrieve the current candidate profile. I guess it can be required by many componants. On this case you don't want to ask again and again server to retreive this information, but may ask it only once then use cached data. no need to switch to promise, just used another observable stream as pruposed on my answer. Hope is more clear now

Answer (score 1):

That is not always the best way to do things. You should not return the observable on your service file. The standard practice is to return the observable on your component itself.

In terms of error handling, you can either do it on your service, or on your component. For the example I am providing below, I will be handling the errors on the component.

On your service, you will need to add the return statement:

```
getProfile(id, token) {
  const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
    })
  };

  return this.http.get(`users/${id}`, httpOptions);
}
```

On your component.ts, you subscribe to it to return the observable value:

```
this.auth.candidateProfile.subscribe( data => {
  console.log(data)
}, error => {
  // handle error
});
```

Comment: But if I want to share the profile in all my pages without subscribing to it in every page ?

Comment: In that case, you can return it as an observable on your service.  However, you will still need to need to carry out the necessary steps to unsubscribe to it.